# Materialize navbar Show/Hide specific Menu based on Condition

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar, material-ui

I want to show/hide navbar user login. 
in my case for eg i am having 2 types of user,
one user ca able to access 4 menu's and another can access 3 only.

like this image [image]

I wish to set `{display:none;}` based on condition . i wish to write it under custom HTML attributes. how do i achieve this?

I need solution something like Angular `ng-show`/ `ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

You can add to body/html tag new class depending on your user and hide/show elements using css.

Or pass params (ex. ?user=admin) to url, check it using javascript and do what you want with DOM.

Comment: I need solution something like Angular `ng-show`/ `ng-if` . i am having user data and having more than 100 url . if its small its easy to achieve as you said

Comment: You said about only 2 types of users. 

use nested inline if-then statement

`<body ng-class=" ... ? 'class-1' : ( ... ? 'class-2' : 'class-3')">`

Comment: no i said for eg... there are more different types are there

Answer (score 0):

You can add the hide class on the element you want to hide.

```
class="hide"
```